# Create a json string with List<NameValuePair> in android

Tags: java, android, json, http

I want to send a http request to a url with Android.
I am an iOS developer and now trying to learn Android.
I used to send the `JSON` string in iOS like below

```
 {"function":"login", "parameters": {"username": "nithin""password": "123456"}}
```

How can I send this in Android?
I tried `List<NameValuePair>` but can't find the proper solution.

Full code of what I tried -

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("function", "login"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "nithin"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "123456"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think JsonStringer is easy and useful for you here..

Try this:

```
   HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);
   request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
   request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
   JSONStringer vm;
   try {
         vm = new JSONStringer().object().key("function")
        .value(login).key("parameters").object()
        .key("username")
        .value(nithin).key("password").value("123456")
        .endObject().endObject();
  StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(vm.toString());
  request.setEntity(entity);
  HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Comment: simply: Bufferedreader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent())); then as usual while loop and readline...

Comment: thanks man..I got the string as {"main":{"status":"true","id":"3","username":"Christian Martin","password":"123456","email":"nithin@newagesmb.com","message":"You have successfully logged in","image":"http:\/\/www.menchd.com\/assets\/upload\/users\/1386921988.jpg","terms_status":"Y","chat_status":"Y","profile_count":4568},"questions":{"total_questions":40,"answerd_questions":40}}                  From this how to fetch the value of a key - for "status"

Comment: no. use `EntityUtils.toString`. using BufferedReader and readLine does not make any sense. There is no indication that there are even lines in the result. And `readLine` reads each character one by one, which is very slow.

Comment: EntityUtils also deprecated ,now which one should I use...?